# He creado el archivo respondive para el css pero no lo detecta

Tags: html5, css3

He creado esta pagina web desde 0 es la primera que hago la pagina inicial esta como la quiero es basico pero si bajan un poco en el area de LO MAS VISTO EN HUECAS BARES Y DISCOTECAS , hay un enlace a un bar que cuando entra no aparece el modo responsive de su archivo RESPON.CSS, el archivo esta llamado desde el index e la misma cuando en google chrome reduzco la pagina hasta menos de 800px funciona pero cuando lo pongo en modo telefono movil no funciona, espero me puedan ayudar ya que estoy iniciando con este protecto la pagina en el que pueden verlo es esta

https://blackknight8789.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Deberias poner el codigo el cual estas usando, para si porder ayudarte si tienes algun error en el

Comment: Acabo de mirar tu página web en view source y parece que no tienes ningún `respon.css`

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo resolvi faltaban las etiquetas META en la pagina index si las tengo puestas y en la pagina del bar no estaban algo raro pero se resolvió colocando las meta. muchas gracias por la respuesta